# Filtering table with date range controller

Tags: looker-studio

I am using Google Data Studio to filter data for a report.

I have the following simple report:

[image]

My default date range is auto:

[image]

The field is configured as `date`:

[image]

As you can see the report does not display only records that have or are between a certain date:

[image]

In my example the report should cut of dates that are before the `24th of January`.

Why is this not the case?

**UPDATE**

Please find below the link to a test report, which reproduces the problem:

https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/3899f199-e064-4816-9dcc-5c9047472427

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data filter applies to the Column in the field "Date Range Dimension". By using In BigQuery partitioned tables are common to reduce data traffic. Data Studio let you preselect this column. I fix the report.

[image]

To remove the preselected column for the data filter in BigQuery, please edit the datasource in Data Studio and uncheck this:
[image]